# What are good machine learning projects for a senior student?

Tags: options, finance, money-management

I'm a senior year student, I study software engineering, I recently started with a machine learning tutorial, I want a machine learning projects that are not hard to make and at the same time good for the community, and people are willing to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts that I'm interested in at the moment...

1. A Deep Hedging-stype approach to risk management (eg. https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3355706)

Fundamentally all of derivative pricing quant finance is Model-Driven. Why? Probably mostly because it's easier. However, we now have maybe 30 years of high frequency tick data available globally for many exchange traded instruments, can we come up with data-driven Greeks models (eg. Delta is just the change in price when the underlying moves, why not measure it directly instead of assuming a model?) For risk management and hedging?

2. Better understanding of the market's Data Generating Process (aka. the holy grail)

Can we use data to simulate spot paths that are better than 'stoch vol with x vol-of-vol'? If you could, then all of trading strategy research becomes easier. Of course, this involves understanding market regime shifts etc...